# How to merge all dataframe columns into a single one in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I know how to manually merge **specific** columns of a dataframe into a single column:

```
df_new <- data.frame(paste(df$a, df$b, df$c))
```

My question is how can I do this dynamically with all of the dataframe's columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution from the tidyverse could be tidyr::unite():

```
df <- data.frame(x = letters[1:4], y = LETTERS[1:4], z = 1:4)
df_new <- tidyr::unite(df, col = "union", sep = " ")
```

where *col* is the name of the newly constructed column in the dataframe. *sep* is equivalent to its use in paste.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `do.call`: *‘do.call’ constructs and executes a function call from a name or a function and a list of arguments to be passed to it.*

```
do.call(paste, df)
```